# How to pass EC named curve list used by SSL_CTX?

Tags: ssl, openssl, cryptography, elliptic-curve

I need to pass the selected EC named curve list to server. What is the OpenSSL API to achieve the same while generating the `SSL_CTX`.

Answer (score 3):

> I need to pass the selected EC named curve list to server. What is the OpenSSL API to achieve the same while generating the `SSL_CTX`.

Its not possible in OpenSSL 1.0.1 and below. You have to hack the source code.

For OpenSSL 1.0.2 and above, use [`SSL_CTX_set1_curves`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/ssl/SSL_CTX_set1_curves.html).

---

If you are hacking the source code for OpenSSL 1.0.0 and 1.0.1, then modify `pref_list` from `t1_lib.c`:

```
static int my_pref_list[] =
{
NID_sect571r1, /* sect571r1 (14) */
NID_sect571k1, /* sect571k1 (13) */
NID_secp521r1, /* secp521r1 (25) */
NID_sect409k1, /* sect409k1 (11) */
NID_sect409r1, /* sect409r1 (12) */
NID_secp384r1, /* secp384r1 (24) */
NID_sect283k1, /* sect283k1 (9) */
NID_sect283r1, /* sect283r1 (10) */
NID_secp256k1, /* secp256k1 (22) */
NID_X9_62_prime256v1, /* secp256r1 (23) */
NID_sect239k1, /* sect239k1 (8) */
NID_sect233k1, /* sect233k1 (6) */
NID_sect233r1, /* sect233r1 (7) */
NID_secp224k1, /* secp224k1 (20) */
NID_secp224r1, /* secp224r1 (21) */
};
```

Also see [OpenSSL RT Issue 3179, Feature Request: Set Preference List for EC Curves in Client](http://rt.openssl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=3179&user=guest&pass=guest).